# Can't make Gmail imap returned content to readable text

Tags: php, gmail-imap, cyrillic

I can't make Gmail imap returned content to readable text.

```
    $imap = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "xxx@gmail.com", "xxx" ) or die( 'IMAP connection error' );

    if( $imap ) {

        $num = imap_num_msg($imap);
        $header = imap_header( $imap , $num  );
        echo $header->subject;
        imap_close($imap);
}
```

The result is

```
=?KOI8-R?B?78LOz9fMxc7JxSDT1MHU2Mk=?=
```

How to echo this text readable? like `Обновление статьи`

Comment: Did you try http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php ?